# n-th element of recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I want to find formula for n-th element of recursively entered sequence using generating functions. It goes like this 
 $$a_{1} = 0, a_{2} = 1, a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_{n} + 2$$

I rewrite this into generating functions like this:

$$a(x) = x(a(x)) + x^{2}(a(x)) + \frac{2}{1-x}-x-2$$

Then I end up with

$$ a(x) = -\frac{x}{-x^{2}-x+1}$$

I want to split this to partial fractions, but roots of denominator are 
$$x_{1} = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, x_{2} = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Problem is I cannot split it and if I could I cannnot say what sequence is generated by generating functions like 
$$ \frac{A}{x + \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}, \frac{B}{x + \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}} $$

I'd appriciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not work out the coefficients $A,B$ in the usual way? I got something like $\pm\sqrt{5}$ but I wrote denominators as $(1-x\alpha)$, $(1-x\beta)$ where $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of $t^2-t-1$.

Comment: And then we just have a couple of $(1-y)^{-1}$ to expand. We'll get something like a constant multiple of $\alpha^n+\beta^n$.

Comment: If you can avoid generating functions, just note that $b_n = a_n +2$ is a shifted Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it almost always happens, the problem is in being very precise with the indexes. Start with 
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}a_nx^{n-1}=a_1+a_2x+\sum\limits_{n=3}a_nx^{n-1}=\\
x+\sum\limits_{n=3}(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+2)x^{n-1}=
x+\sum\limits_{n=3}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\sum\limits_{n=3}a_{n-2}x^{n-1}+2\sum\limits_{n=3}x^{n-1}=\\
x+\sum\limits_{n=2}a_{n}x^{n}+\sum\limits_{n=1}a_{n}x^{n+1}+2\sum\limits_{n=2}x^{n}=\\
x+x\sum\limits_{n=2}a_{n}x^{n-1}+x^2\sum\limits_{n=1}a_{n}x^{n-1}+2\sum\limits_{n=2}x^{n}=\\
x+x(f(x)-0)+x^2f(x)+2\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-x-1\right)$$

leading to
$$f(x)(1-x-x^2)=x+\frac{2x^2}{1-x}=\frac{x+x^2}{1-x}$$
or 
$$\color{red}{f(x)=\frac{x+x^2}{(1-x)(1-x-x^2)}}=-\frac{x+x^2}{(1-x)\left(x+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}=...$$
let's [note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) by $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\psi=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$
$$...=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}(1+\psi)(x+\psi)} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}(1+\varphi)(x+\varphi)} - \frac{2}{(1+\psi)(1+\varphi)(1-x)}=\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\psi(1+\psi)\left(1+\frac{x}{\psi}\right)} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\varphi(1+\varphi)\left(1+\frac{x}{\varphi}\right)} - \frac{2}{(1+\psi)(1+\varphi)(1-x)}=\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\psi(1+\psi)}\sum\limits_{n=1}\left(-\frac{x}{\psi}\right)^{n-1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\varphi(1+\varphi)}\sum\limits_{n=1}\left(-\frac{x}{\varphi}\right)^{n-1}-\frac{2}{(1+\psi)(1+\varphi)}\sum\limits_{n=1}x^{n-1}=\\
\sum\limits_{n=1}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\psi(1+\psi)}\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\psi}\right)^{n-1} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\varphi(1+\varphi)}\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\varphi}\right)^{n-1} -\frac{2}{(1+\psi)(1+\varphi)} \right)x^{n-1}$$
thus
$$\color{red}{a_n=}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\psi(1+\psi)}\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\psi}\right)^{n-1} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\varphi(1+\varphi)}\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\varphi}\right)^{n-1} -\frac{2}{(1+\psi)(1+\varphi)}=\\
\color{red}{\left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\psi}\right)^{n-1} +\left(1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\varphi}\right)^{n-1} -2}$$
and to confirm
$$a_1=\left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\cdot 1 +\left(1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\cdot 1 -2=0$$
[$$a_2=\left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\psi}\right) +\left(1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\varphi}\right) -2=1$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D)*(-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B1-%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D%7B2%7D%7D)%20%2B(1-%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D)*(-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%2B%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D%7B2%7D%7D)-2)
[$$a_3=3$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D)*(-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B1-%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D%7B2%7D%7D)%5E2%20%2B(1-%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D)*(-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%2B%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D%7B2%7D%7D)%5E2-2)